# How to store European Currency in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

On a new project I work on I have data in CSV format to import into a mysql table. One of the columns is a price field which stores currency in the european format ie. 345,83. 
The isssue I have is storing this decimal seperator. In most European currencies the decimal seperator is "," but when I try to insert a decimal number into a field (ex. 345,83), I get the following error: "Data truncated for column 'column_name' at row 'row #'". If I use '.' instead of ',' it works fine. Could you please help me with, how to store this format in mysql?

Comment: Just to clarify - this is not exactly a mysql problem, but a question about parsing European numbers? If you've had this column as a double you'd know what to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can store it as a regular decimal field in the database, and format the number european style when you display it

edit: just added an example of how it might be achieved

```
$european_numbers = array('123.345,78', '123 456,78', ',78');

foreach($european_numbers as $number) {

    echo "$number was converted to ".convert_european_to_decimal($number)."\n";
    // save in database now
}

function convert_european_to_decimal($number) {
    // i am sure there are better was of doing this, but this is nice and simple example
    $number = str_replace('.', '', $number); // remove fullstop
    $number = str_replace(' ', '', $number); // remove spaces
    $number = str_replace(',', '.', $number); // change comma to fullstop

    return $number;
}
```

Comment: As I understood the OP that's exactly what he tries to do but fails due to the fact that MySQL uses the dot as the decimal separator. You cannot store values with a comma in a DECIMAL column.

Answer (score 4):

Use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [money_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), it's pretty much what you preffer.

Comment: please be aware that money_format() is undefined on windows systems

Answer (score 3):

It's worse than you think. The number `1234.56` may be written in Europe as:

1. 1234,56
2. 1 234,56 (space as a group separator)
3. 1.234,56 (dot as a group separator)

In .net the number parser can works according to a given culture, so if you know the format it does the hard work for you. I'm sure you can find a PHP equivalent, it'd save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You could import the currency field into a `VARCHAR` column and then copy this column into a `DECIMAL` column while replacing the `,` by a `.` in all rows using MySQL string-manipulation-functions.

```
UPDATE <<table>>
    SET <<decimal-currency-col>> = REPLACE(<<varchar-currency-col>>, ',', '.');
```

Comment: @S. Gehrig: Correct, but a bit overkill considering the OP is using PHP.

Comment: That depends: if the OP has to some calculations (some accumulations for example) on the MySQL side, he has to store the values in an appropriate data type.

Answer (score 0):

> Some data types do not have a direct
>   correlation between SQL Server or
>   Access and MySQL. One example would be
>   the CURRENCY data type: MySQL does not
>   (yet) have a CURRENCY data type, but
>   creating a column with the definition
>   DECIMAL(19,4) serves the same purpose.
>   While MSSQL defaults to Unicode
>   character types such as nCHAR and
>   nVARCHAR, MySQL does not so tightly
>   bind character sets to field types,
>   instead allowing for one set of
>   character types which can be bound to
>   any number of character sets,
>   including Unicode.

from http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider multiplying it by 100 and storing it as INT.

Before inserting the price to the DB:

```
$price = (int)$price*100;
```

After receiving price from the DB:

```
$price = number_format($price, 2, ',', ' ');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try replacing the "," with "."?

$price = str_replace(",", ".", $price);
```

Comment: @Thilo. Yes I think it should be a dot in this case as it appears to be the decimal separator.

In the UK we use a comma as the thousands separator and a dot for the decimal e.g. 1,250.25

However the French and other European countries use them the otherway round e.g. 1.250,00.