# Displaying Float on Input Forms

Tags: forms, cakephp

I'm fairly new to the CakePHP game and need some insight on how to resolve a seemingly simple issue. I've inherited a few internal websites at my new job that utilize the framework and am struggling to tackle this issue with Google alone.

What I have is a view that loads a form and populates it with data already in the database. There are three fields that have this behavior and all have the same issue.

The fields are declared as such on the View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('hotel_costs');
echo $this->Form->input('misc_costs');
```

Within the database they're declared as `float` DataTypes and therefore, when loaded to the browser will sometimes display as floats do: (15.7 becoming 15.699999999...)

Looking around it seems there are Helpers such as NumberHelper able to tackle my issue but I have no clue how to include the functionality with the form values. Am I looking in the wrong place entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with forcing the input type to text.  Are you saying that you don't want the float's value in the field, but you want a rounded (to how many decimal places) number instead?  It would have to apply across the board.  Do you have a custom view or a baked one?
(I'd ask these as comments to your question, but my rep aint high enough.)

Comment: The value of float on the database field is saved as 15.7. But when CakePHP goes to build the form it populates the fields with 15.699999. I'm lookiing for a way to have float values display on the input field properly (rounded, truncated, whatever is necessary) without effecting functionality: the ability to display, change and save a value using the input form. This is a custom View I'm assuming, not sure what you mean by "baked"

Comment: Check out this answer.  I believe you need to write an afterFind method.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270372/1778068

By baked, I mean did you use the console command cake bake to generate some of your code.

Comment: Instead of writing an event handler, you could also just change the view to write the rounded value as the "default" value for the input field of the form as this example shows from the Common Options section of this manual page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html.
`echo $this->Form->input('ingredient', array('default' => 'Sugar'));`
Of course you'd need to replace 'Sugar' with `$this->Number->precision($this->YourModelName->hotel_costs, 2);`

Comment: Thanks for the links marvin. I was able to resolve the issue by creating a `afterFind()` function on the Model that executes `number_format()` on the affected rows as per  your comment.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to force input[type=text], so that cake doesn't try to guess input type.

```
$this->Form->input('hotel_costs', array(
   'type' => 'text'
));
$this->Form->input('misc_costs', array(
   'type' => 'text'
));
```

if this still doesn't work, post back with more details.

1. Which Controller Action(add/index/edit)?
2. Code of that action
3. `var_dump()` of data from the database