# cakephp format money to locale

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have an input which sets a salary value into the database. My problem is that if I enter 20,000 it get set in the database as 20.00

I am in Ireland so the comma denotes thousands, not a decimal

I have tried changing the locale setting in the appController but it is still happening.

```
public function beforeFilter() {  
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_GB.UTF-8"); 
}
```

The database field is set to decimal 9,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePhp will not handle this kind of conversions automatically when saving. It's probably best to perform some checks and/or conversions in the beforeValidate() callback of your model.

Some hints can be found here

[Validating and transforming decimal values in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270284/validating-and-transforming-decimal-values-in-cakephp)