# MySQL select and sort Euro Currency

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a plugin that is used to sort Wordpress posts based on a custom field. This field is a price field. The plugin works perfectly for all country that use euro and usd. I have a client who is from Holland which uses euro but have special characters to define cents. These special characters have thrown a wrench into the plugin where it is causing sort errors.

Here is the MySQL code to retrieve and sort by price:

```
function price_sort_it() {
global $wpdb, $thisorder;

    if($thisorder == 'price-lowest') {
        $this_order = 'ASC';
    }
    else if($thisorder == 'price-highest') {
        $this_order = 'DESC';
    }

return "(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, ',', ''), '€',''),' ','') AS SIGNED)
           FROM $wpdb->postmeta
          WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'ad_price')" . $this_order;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'price_sort_it');
```

This code removes the thousand comma separator and also removes the currency symbol before the sort. It works flawlessly.

The issue is that the Holland client has ads with prices like this:

- € 5
- € 5,-
- € 5,00

Along with normal values like:

- € 10,000
- € 500.29
- € 10

Where the comma represents a decimal and the comma and negative represent an abbreviation of decimal and 2 zeros.

Any words of the wise on how to tackle this feat?

Comment: Are those three the only cases?

Comment: FYI, Holland is not a country. It is a region in the western part of the Netherlands. There are 12 provinces in the Netherlands, North and South Holland are just 2 of them. Sorry for off-topic :)

Comment: the issue is client training, train him\her on what format price must be in.

Comment: @Dragon -lol Trust me, i agree! They need to get with the program lol

Comment: you may think its funny, but training is one of the most important parts.

Comment: @njk - No, they would still have regular values like 10,000, 100, 50.29, etc,...

Comment: @Dagon - I agree, but the site already has several hundred Ads. SO it would be hard to change the process now. Im tempted to give up on this client.

Comment: I've given up on this question, good luck

Comment: @thesanerone Is the issue converting it to a standard format (USD) for sorting? Or is the issue just converting the Euro format (with commas) for storage? If it's the latter, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118264/how-to-store-european-currency-in-mysql.

Comment: @njk - yes, to the first question. The conversion would be needed just to sort.

Answer (score 2):

You describe the client's number formats as not being "normal" formatting. This is the first alarm bell for me.

There's nothing "normal" or otherwise about formatting numbers with points or commas in any particular place. Different countries have different formatting conventions, and in fact *most* countries use a comma as the decimal character and a point as the thousands separator. This applies to virtually all continental European countries.

So don't consider your preferred formatting as "normal". The client sees their formatting as normal and yours as weird. And the client is the one who is paying for it.

The standard way of dealing with this is to handle all the numbers unformatted within your program, and display them in the formatting required by the client using PHP's [`number_format()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

For example:

```
$number_in_dutch_format = number_format($unformatted_number, 2, ',', '.');
```

You can make the comma and point into variables, so you can make it configurable in your program, so each customer can have whatever formatting they prefer.

If you need more complex formatting, functions such as [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) may also be useful.

The one thing that you should specify, however, is that you should stick to a single format for a given client.

You could also read other questions on the subject here on SO, like this one: [PHP: Locale aware number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371/php-locale-aware-number-format)

Hope that helps.